# Fibonacci gcd proof

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, fibonacci-numbers

How to prove that gcd of Fibonacci numbers set is $1$, I mean

$\gcd(a_{n+1},a_{n})=\gcd(a_{n},a_{n−1})$

because of Euclidean algorithm

$\gcd(a_{n+1},a_{n})=\gcd(a_{n},r)$

$r$ - the remainder after division of $a_{n+1}$ by $a_{n}$

but

$r=a_{n−1}$

it means that

$\gcd(a_{n+1},a_{n})=\gcd(a_{n},a_{n−1})$

And

$\gcd(a_{3},a_{2})=\gcd(a_{2},a_{1}) = 1$

it means that gcd of Fibonacci numbers set is $1$, right ?

Comment: Yes, the greatest common divisor of two successive Fibonacci numbers is $1$. More generally, assuming the indexing is such that $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$, we have $$\gcd (a_n, a_k) = a_{\gcd(n,k)}\,.$$

Comment: Another approach: prove by induction that $a_n^2 - a_{n+1} a_{n-1} = (-1)^{n-1}$ from which it should be easy to conclude that $\gcd(a_{n+1}, a_n) = 1$.  (Essentially, this is just saying what the result is of applying the extended Euclidean algorithm to get a Bezout pair for $a_n, a_{n+1}$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCD of all Fibonacci numbers is 1 simply because 1 is a Fibonacci number. There is nothing to prove here.

If you want to prove that consecutive Fibonacci numbers are relatively prime:

Suppose that there is some number $p$ dividing $a_{k}$ and $a_{k+1}$ for some $k$. It means that $p$ also divides their difference which is $a_{k+1}-a_k=a_{k-1}$. Repeat the same process and you’ll find out that $p$ also divides $a_{k-2}$, $a_{k-3}$, ..., $a_{1}=1$, which is possible only if $p=1$. So consecutive numbers must be coprime.